# Как проверить наличие русских букв в строке?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Какое регулярное выражение поможет узнать, есть ли хоть одна русская буква в строке среди латинницы? Пробовал:

```
preg_match("/^[а-я]/i",$this->open_metka_value,$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Проверял словом `taБle` – не реагирует.

Comment: включите поддержку юникода модификатором `u`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос, отметьте его как "верный".

Comment: Пора бы ответ принять...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В вашем регулярном выражении есть три проблемы:

1. Вы используете символ `^`, который привязывает регулярное выражение к началу строки. Например выражению `/^abc/` будут соответствовать строки `abcd` и `abc def`, но не `defabc`.
2. PHP не совсем корректно работает кириллицей (как, впрочем, и с рядом других UTF символов). А для того, чтобы все-таки заставить его работать корректно, нужно использовать модификатор `u`, включающий поддержку Unicode в регулярном выражении.
3. Диапазон символов `а-я` не включает в себя символ `ё` (код этой буквы в кодировке UTF не попадает в диапазон между кодами букв `а` и `я`).

Таким образом, корректное регулярное выражение имеет вид:

```
/[а-яё]/iu
```

Comment: [Тест](http://ideone.com/4Yqxxs), подтверждающий правильность ответа.

Comment: благодарю за пояснение . очень помогли

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Строка с русскими буквами";
//получаем true или false в зависимости есть ли русские буквы в строке
$res = isContainsRussianLetters($string);
```

Код функции тут http://blog.ivru.net/?id=232

```
function isContainsRussianLetters($text = false) {
  if ($text !== "") {
    $len = strlen($text)-1;
    for ($i=0;$i<=$len;$i++) {
      if (($i < $len) and (((($ord = ord(substr($text,$i,1))) == 208) 
                      and (($ord2 = ord(substr($text,($i+1),1))) == 129) 
                      or (($ord2 >= 144) and ($ord2 <= 191))) 
                      or ((($ord = ord(substr($text,$i,1))) == 209) 
                      and ($ord2 == 145) or (($ord2 >= 128) 
                      and ($ord2 <= 143))))) {
        //Поиск русских букв в UTF-8
        return true;
      } elseif (((($ord = ord(substr($text,$i,1))) >= 192) 
             and (($ord <= 255)) or ($ord == 168) or ($ord == 184))) {
        //Поиск русских букв в ANSI
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

работает для кодировок UTF-8 и windows=1251(cp1251) не зависимо от регистра и не требует установки локали, последнее для меня как раз и было важно, единственное Вы простили регулярку, а это не регулярка.

Comment: Этот ответ плохой и формально и по сути. Формально потому что не содержит ответа, а только ссылку на постороннюю страницу. А страницы имеют свойство пропадать. по сути потому, что код всегда должен знать, в какой кодировке русский текст, иначе его просто невозможно будет обрабатывать дальше - вывести на страницу, записать в файл или базу данных. поэтому кодировко-независимая функция не имеет применения.